# What's wrong with my code?-js

Tags: javascript

I have written a code & I don't know what is wrong with it.
When i try to use it in html, it does not work at all.`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;` is the error. Please Help!
The he.js code is:

```
x:
var b = parseInt(Math.random()*100);
var a = prompt("Guess a number");
if (a>b)
{
var c= prompt("Enter bigger");
else if (a<b)
{
var d = prompt("Enter smaller");
}
else
{
var e = prompt("you win! Do you want to play again(Y/N)");
}
if (e == "Y")
{
goto x;
}
```

The game.html code is:

```
<html>
<body>
<script src = "he.js">
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Why do You think there's something wrong with it? What's Your question?

Comment: Can you explain what it is supposed to do?

Comment: Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the console. **Read the error messages**

Comment: Firstly your missing a closing bracket on your first `if`. Also `goto` isn't supported in JavaScript, use a `while` loop.

Comment: some indentation would help to keep track of nested elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing closing curly bracket on your first if clause:

```
if (a>b)
{
var c= prompt("Enter bigger");
} // <-- That one
else if (a<b)
```

and in addition, there's no `goto` in JS so this loop should be completly rewritten.